# What's the difference between `def` and `defp`

Tags: elixir

I'm going through the Programming Phoenix book and I am wondering what the difference between `def` and `defp` is.

There are several functions in my controller - most of them are actions like this:

```
def new (conn, _params) do
...
end
```

The book had me create another function in this controller that is not a typical controller action like this:

```
defp user_videos(user) do
...
end
```

So my question is how do I know when to use `defp` and when to use `def` when defining a function in Elixir?

Comment: This is true of all of Elixir--not just the Phoenix Framework.  It's a property of Elixir--not of the framework.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

From [Elixir’s documentation on functions within modules](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules.html#named-functions):

> Inside a module, we can define functions with `def/2` and private functions with `defp/2`. A function defined with `def/2` can be invoked from other modules while a private function can only be invoked locally.

So `defp` defines a private function.

Answer (score 7):

> So my question is how do I know when to use defp and when to use def when defining a function inside a controller in the Phoenix Framework.

`def` functions of a module can be called from other modules, whereas `defp` functions are private, or not callable from other modules. How do you know when to use `def` and when to use `defp`? It depends on what other modules may or may not need to know about. A common design pattern is for a module to provide a parent `def` function that wraps all the behavior of its `defp`functions:

```
defmodule MyModule do

  def function do
    # call all the defp functions below to do something
  end

  defp function2 do
    # do something that no other module cares about or needs to know about
  end

  defp function3 do
    # do something that no other module cares about or needs to know about
  end

  defp function4 do
    # do something that no other module cares about or needs to know about
  end
end
```

Here is an example of this with a parser for SEC filings: [SEC Company Filings Parser](https://github.com/vikram7/sec_company_filings_rss_feed_parser/blob/master/lib/feed.ex). The main `def` method wraps all the private functions which no other module really needs to know about.